# Do I need to specify the initial size of Lists when programming for Android?

Tags: java, android

For Android programming, if I'm creating an ArrayList in a method and know how big the list is going to be when I return it from the method, should I specify the initial size of the list when I'm creating it?

I'm asking because typically we don't bother specifying an initial size, but maybe it makes a difference when programming for mobile.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I'm talking about the cases where I *do* know what the final size of the list will be (e.g. I'm creating a list of objects of type B from a list of objects of type A).

**Edit 2**

Are there any performance metrics relating to this?

Comment: If you are list is \dynamic, then it may be helpful. But I think better not worry about performance gains with these changes unless you see real issue.

Comment: If you do know the size there is NO reason why you should not use it to instantiate the list - that's what the constructor that takes a capacity is for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you know how big the list is going to be, you should definitely specify the initial size. It will increase the performance.

If you use the default constructor, the initial size will be 0. From [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29):

> `public ArrayList()` Constructs a new `ArrayList` instance with **zero** initial
>   capacity.

And the code:

```
public ArrayList() {
    array = EmptyArray.OBJECT;
}
```

So, later when you are adding elements, the inner `Object[] array` will be resized:

```
@Override public boolean add(E object) {
    Object[] a = array;
    int s = size;
    if (s == a.length) {
        Object[] newArray = new Object[s +
                (s < (MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT / 2) ?
                 MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT : s >> 1)];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, s);
        array = a = newArray;
    }
    a[s] = object;
    size = s + 1;
    modCount++;
    return true;
}
```

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/ArrayList.java) is the code of Android's `ArrayList`.

So, to not waste time for resizing, it's better to specify the initial size of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` is designed to automatically adjust itself based on its content. You may preallocate memory, but it will eventually be adjusted based on how you use the `ArrayList`. It shouldn't matter unless you're building an enormous list that will persist for a while as Java uses garbage collection for heap clean up.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the List, or any collection, it is by far more performant to specify the size ahead of time.  The reason is because it takes cycles to grow a Collection, depending on the implementation maybe more maybe less.

Answer (score 0):

I think the same stands here as in any other java application. You shouldn't care about these micro-optimizations only if it proves to be a bottleneck. The data structures in the JCF have reasonable defaults:

```
ArrayList() {
     this(10);
}
```

This is the default for an `ArrayList`.

What you should pay attention to is the *space* and *time* complexity of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ArrayList is designed to handle with dynamic sizes, but if previously you know how much items your list will have, is a good practice initiate with the size specified, is easier to other dev's to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

So in my experience, unless you're anticipating a scaling problem once you've deployed (not sure exactly what you want to use your List for, so, just to be safe) there's no reason to specify the size. I mean, if you know FOR SURE that it'll always be 10, well, then by all means. That'll be great.

Now what you CAN do is tuck the insert commands into a cheap (performance) IF statement to do some memory management. Find out whatever device(s) you're targeting and come up with a reasonable amount of space in memory that you're comfortable taking up for your app. If the insert statement would go over that, prompt the user with an option to go ahead and risk performance issues, deny the insert completely, or maybe start deleting old stuff.

Again, not knowing your exact situation it's a bit hard to advise, but in general, if you CAN ABSOLUTELY SAY that the List will max out at 10, by all means initialize to 10. But you're not going to hurt much if you just let it tick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should pass the capacity to the constructor for an `ArrayList` in this case, here's why:

The constructor you would call is the following:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

By passing the `initialCapacity` you're setting the size of the array that backs the `ArrayList`.

Say you're going to add to the list, and that element would cause the list to resize.  Here's the series of function calls that would take place:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}

private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    if (elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
    }

    ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
}

private void ensureExplicitCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;

    // overflow-conscious code
    if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
        grow(minCapacity);
}

private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

In conclusion, if you know the final size, by passing it to the constructor, you're going to guarantee that the array never needs to be re-sized.

If the final capacity is sufficiently large and the `ArrayList` is going to be relatively unpopulated for an extended period of time, then you may not want to allocate that much memory, ie it may be better to have it resize itself when necessary.  Otherwise, I'd pass the initial capacity.